# Validate a not required input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to validate a phone number, but the same should not be required if left empty?

- If the input is **empty** - the form **should submit**
- If a phone number is entered, then its **required that it be 10 digits**.
- If it **doesn't match the 10 digits pattern** - than the form should **not submit**

Please advise, thank you

Comment: So in short: **How to validate a *non required* input**.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Do you have some validation code which isn't working as you hoped? If so please show it, so we can fix it. Otherwise your question is a bit abstract.

Comment: sorry I don't know that. I want to validate non required input. Roko C is right.<label>Phone Number:
<input name="customer_phone" type="text" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" required pattern=" " />
     </label>

Comment: Just remove the "required" attribute from that code

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `required` attribute you're **game over. So don't.**

> *its required that it be 10 digits*

Use the `^\d{10}$` pattern:

```css
input[type=text]:invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^\d{10}$" />
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

The form **doesn't submits** if

1. There's some value **AND** the value does not matches the regex in `pattern`.

The form **submits** if

1. There's no value
2. There's value **AND** has exactly 10 digits

Comment: this will show border red but still, I can submit even I type two numbers. do I have to add required attribute so they can't submit the form

Comment: @LiWen you're doing something wrong. See again my example. See? I cannot submit the form.

Comment: http://rsp-toyotaofnatchez.fzautomotive.com/inventory?type=new&keyword=RAV4 Hi Roko the best price form I tried removed the required attribute if you leave phone field empty I cant submit the form

Comment: @LiWen on that button there is a "validateForm" function which runs, as well as the HTML5 attributes. I would guess that is adding some extra rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to match most phone numbers or an empty string.

```js
var pat = /^$|^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/
console.log(pat.test(''))
console.log(pat.test('8169428451'))
console.log(pat.test('(816)842-8455'))
console.log(pat.test('asdfs'))
```

```js
function check(){
var pat = /^$|^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/
var phone = document.getElementById('phone')
if(pat.test(phone.value))
{
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
else
{
return false
}
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="phone" type="text" />
  <button onclick="check(); return false;">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, Scath thanks for helping but I applied your pattern to my required pattern filed. then I test my form if I don't input phone I can't submit the form

Comment: Is it required field?

Comment: <label>Phone Number:
       <input name="customer_phone" type="text" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx"  pattern="/^$|^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/" />
     </label> this is what i have, this code wont pass empty input, but if i change type="tel" it will pass empty but also any number.

Comment: Try taking the '/' off the beginning and end of the pattern string.

Comment: http://rsp-toyotaofnatchez.fzautomotive.com/inventory?type=new&keyword=RAV4

Comment: i have no idea why here is running fine but once i apply to that site is not working right anymore

Comment: I wrote wrote a click event to not submit or submit the form when the user clicks the submit button, I don't know if you can use this.